# Inserting a anchor with jquery to call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to jQuery, what i am trying to do is once the document is ready, i am creating a field. in a div. At the moment it works like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("div.custom").eq(1).html("<a href='javascript:createPDF(\'Y\')' class=shortButton'>Download PDF</a>");
});
```

Now this doesn't works because the arguments. But I can create something like this

```
$("div.custom a").click(function(e) {  
    //alert('clicked');  
    createPDF('Y');
    return false;
});
```

and in order to change this i change my creation to this

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("div.custom").eq(1).html("<a href='#' class=shortButton'>Download PDF</a>");
});
```

However, i personally believe because it first doesn't exist once the page is loaded, it doesn't connect the link with the click function. How can I proceed with it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("div.custom").eq(1).html("<a href='#' class=shortButton '>DownloadPDF</a>").find("a").click(function(e) {  
        alert('clicked');  
        createPDF('Y');
        return false;
    }); ;
});
```

You are right this is because the link doesn't exist. With the correction I gave you the event is added just after you create the link

Hope it helped

Answer (score 3):

You have to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding event on dynamically created elements. You can use event delegation.

```
$("div.custom").on("click", "a", function(e) {  
    //alert('clicked');  
    createPDF('Y');
    return false;
});
```

#### Delegated events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.custom").on("click", "a", function(event){
   //alert('clicked');  
        createPDF('Y');
        return false;
});
```

see for details..[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) according to jquery

Answer (score 1):

can you try this something like this:

```
$("div.custom").on('click', 'a', function(e) {  
//alert('clicked');  
createPDF('Y');
return false;
});
```

[edit]oups too late ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can hook the event when you add the anchor tag like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.custom").eq(1).html("<a href='#' class=shortButton'>Download PDF</a>").find('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        createPDF('Y');
    });
});
```